# Is negative frequency important in calculating Spectral Moments

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, dft

A follow on question form this one ([What is meant by "spectral moment"?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/what-is-meant-by-spectral-moment))

In answers to the above referenced question spectral moment is defined as:

$$
m_k=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^k|X(f)|^2\ df
$$

The limits on the integral include negative frequency. So is the negative frequency really important?

If I filter out all negative frequencies before calculating the moments will they be wrong?

If $|X_f|^2$ is symmetrical about zero then does this not mean that $m_k=0$ for all odd values of $k$?

Comment: Note that your equation is wrong. You need to take the magnitude squared of the spectrum.

Comment: Ok. Edited. Thanks. How about the point of negative frequency?